# add switch in actbionbar using appcompat in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

Hi I am using a Switch in ActionBar but want to refer to use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` method but it gives me an error in the method

`myswitch = (Switch) menu.findItem(R.id.myswitch).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.switchForActionBar);`

This is my code ...

my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnCheckedChangeListener{
```

my method menu

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_actions, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    MenuItem refr = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
    refr.setVisible(true);
    mySwitch = (Switch)menu.findItem(R.id.myswitch).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.switchForActionBar);
    if ( mySwitch == null ){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        mySwitch.setChecked(true);}
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

but it gives me an error:

```
java.lang.NoShuchMethodError: android.view.MenuItem.getActionView
```

help me please..

Answer (score 0):

Use `MenuItemCompat.getActionView()`

```
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
    final MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item);
    final Switch switch = (Switch) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
```

Considering `R.id.menu_item` is a switch or that you are using a custom layout/view.

IMO your bug is just API-related, that is why you should always use `MenuItemCompat.getActionView()` for compatibility, whatever the API level your device is running.

**EDIT**

I'm sorry I was missleading. Try to use `SwitchCompat` both in XML and code.

Comment: Now show me the following error: Could not find class ' android.widget.Switch ' referenced from method ... I change something in the XML menu or Layout?

Comment: I don't know hot you implemented your `Switch`. Show use your menu's XML if that's where it is.

Comment: My custom design: switch_bar.xml

Comment: I'm using a custom design switch_bar.xml and the menu main_actions.xml, I use <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat ... /> What am I doing wrong?!?

Comment: `menu.findItem()` is to get a menu item, not a layout item (retrieved by `findViewById()`. It looks like you are missing the two... I'll ask clearly: in what file is declared this `SwitchCompat`? res/layout or res/menu?

Comment: res/layout/switch_bar.xml

Comment: Then why are you trying to get it from the menu? Read your code: `Switch = menu.findItem()`... What you are doing wrong is that the `Switch` is not in the menu. Use `findViewById()`.

Comment: Anyway, your initial question was about a `MenuItem.getActionView()` problem, which is solved by using `MenuItemCompat.getActionView()`. Your current question is another one.